# Property 'push' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am having some issue with express app when posting to a route, I am trying to pass some dishIds as shown below through the body of POSTMAN:

```
[
    {"_id":"5f209e066e27a49e582b46bc"},
    {"_id":"5f209e746e27a49e582b46be"}
  
  ]
```

I am trying to save Favorite dish and the schema is show below (favorite.js)(:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('mongoose-currency').loadType(mongoose);


const favoriteSchema = new Schema({
    dishes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Dish'
     }],
     
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
})

var Favorites = mongoose.model('Favorite', favoriteSchema);

module.exports = Favorites;
```

I am trying to save user, dishId into Favourites model but I am getting an error that says " ***Cannot read property 'push' of undefined***", Can anyone help me understand what Ia am getting wrong with POST Route below:
thank you in advance.

```
.post(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, (req, res, next) =>{
    Favorites.create(req.body)
    .then((favorite) => {
       if( favorite != null) {
            req.body.user = req.user._id // get the current user
            favorite.dishes.push(req.body)
            favorite.save()
            .then((favorite) => {
                Favorites.findById(favorite._id)
                     .populate('user')    //populate the user
                     .then((favorite) => {
                        res.statusCode = 200;
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        res.json(favorite);
                     })
             
            }, (err) => next(err))         
       }
       else {
           err = new Error('Dish ' + req.params.dishId + 'not found');
           err.status = 404;
           return next(err);
       }
      
   }, (err) => next(err))     
   .catch((err) => next(err));

})
```

Comment: debug and check what's the value of `favorite` and `favorite.dishes` at Line 4

Comment: This is the output of "favorite"     _doc: {
      dishes: [Array],
      _id: 5f209e066e27a49e582b46bc,
      createdAt: 2020-07-29T02:10:12.855Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-07-29T02:10:12.855Z,
      __v: 0

Comment: assuming req.body is a valid array, try `favorite.dishes.concat(req.body)` or `favorite.dishes.push(...req.body)`

Comment: thanks Karl, Can elaborate little bit? I am a bit lost and stuck

Comment: @user1195182 can you console.log(req.body ) pls, and see what exactly is in it?